# When does the sum of solutions equal $100$?

Tags: equation-solving

How to find the values of the real-valued parameter $a$ for which the sum of real roots of the equation $$\sin \left(\sqrt{a x-x^2}\right)=0 $$ equals $100$? I stop at

```
Solve[Sin[Sqrt[a*x - x^2]] == 0, x, Reals]
```

> `{{x -> 0}, {x -> a},  {x -> ConditionalExpression[a/2 - Sqrt[a^2 - 16*Pi^2*C[1]^2]/ 2, (Element[C[1], Integers] && C[1] >= 1 &&  a > 4*Pi*C[1]) || (Element[C[1], Integers] &&  C[1] >= 1 && a < -4*Pi*C[1])]},  {x -> ConditionalExpression[a/2 + Sqrt[a^2 - 16*Pi^2*C[1]^2]/ 2, (Element[C[1], Integers] && C[1] >= 1 &&  a > 4*Pi*C[1]) || (Element[C[1], Integers] &&  C[1] >= 1 && a < -4*Pi*C[1])]},  {x -> ConditionalExpression[ a/2 - Sqrt[a^2 - 4*Pi^2 - 16*Pi^2*C[1] - 16*Pi^2*C[1]^2]/2,  (Element[C[1], Integers] && a + 4*Pi*C[1] < -2*Pi &&  C[1] >= 0) || (Element[C[1], Integers] && C[1] >= 0 &&  a - 4*Pi*C[1] > 2*Pi)]},  {x -> ConditionalExpression[ a/2 + Sqrt[a^2 - 4*Pi^2 - 16*Pi^2*C[1] - 16*Pi^2*C[1]^2]/2,  (Element[C[1], Integers] && a + 4*Pi*C[1] < -2*Pi &&  C[1] >= 0) || (Element[C[1], Integers] && C[1] >= 0 &&  a - 4*Pi*C[1] > 2*Pi)]}}`

Comment: $a=25$ would do, with the roots $x\in\left\{0,\frac{1}{2} \left(25-\sqrt{625-4 \pi ^2}\right),\frac{1}{2}
   \left(25-\sqrt{625-16 \pi ^2}\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(25-\sqrt{625-36 \pi
   ^2}\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(25+\sqrt{625-36 \pi ^2}\right),\frac{1}{2}
   \left(25+\sqrt{625-16 \pi ^2}\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(25+\sqrt{625-4 \pi
   ^2}\right),25\right\}$.

Comment: @Roman result agreed

Comment: @Roman: Thank you. Is this the only possible value of $a$?

Comment: Yes, the sum is monotonous in $a$.

Comment: @Roman: : Can you ground it?

Comment: I cannot ground it to your excessive requirements.

Comment: @Roman: Please be correct. Your claim  "excessive requirements" does not make a good impression.

Answer (score 9):

```
F[a_] := Sum[{1/2 (a - Sqrt[a^2 - 4 n^2 \[Pi]^2]), 
              1/2 (a + Sqrt[a^2 - 4 n^2 \[Pi]^2])}, {n, 0, Floor[a/(2 \[Pi])]}] // Total

F[25] // FullSimplify
(*    100    *)
```

Comment: 1. From where `Floor[a/(2 \[Pi])]}]` and `25`?  2. This is rather intuition, not math. 3. Unfortunately, such an answer cannot be accepted.

Comment: `Solve[F[a] == 100, a, Reals]` returns the input.

Comment: @user64494 Your equation is fullfilled if `x(a-x)==(n Pi)^2, Element[n,Integers]`, real solutions only exist if `-a<2Pi n<a` . That 's the way Roman took, in a straightforward mathematical manner !!!.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Think of `a==2*Pi*n` (see the result of `Solve[Sin[Sqrt[a*x - x^2]] == 0, x, Reals]`) and master your math.

Comment: `NSolve[F[a] == 100, a, Reals]` fais too.

Comment: "master your math"  is an unacceptable impudence! Perhaps you might find someone explaining Roman's solution idea.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: I also master my math in my seventies. Your cllaim `-a<2*Pi* n<a` is not true as noticed in my comment.

Comment: @user64494 your level of trolling this forum is really taxing my patience. I will stop reacting/replying to your input here.

Comment: @Roman: Please, be correct.

Comment: (+1 ) @user64494  user64494 always make unreasonable demands.